# Drupal 7 views accordion doesn't work

Tags: view, drupal-7, drupal-views, accordion, taxonomy

Hi I've installed the views accordion module to display a list of cocktails using taxonomy and it's not working for me.

My taxonomy looks like this

Drinks

1. Classics

   - Drink 1 & ingredients
   - Drink 2 & ingredients
   - ...more
2. Signatures

   - Drink 1 & ingredients
   - Drink 2 & ingredients
   - ...more

I want the accordion to display 2 clickable options classics and signatures and when clicking on any of the 2, it will display a list of drinks.

What I get is classics, drink 1, drink 2, signatures, drink 1, drink 2 all as clickable options. I've also tried creating an accordion without using my taxonomy list and I can't manually create one.

Can someone point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use views field grouping available when you choose to define the row formatter.